# while query does not get the first item

Tags: php, mysql

my query does get the items but not all of them. the firs one does not get excuted. what am i going to do about it?

```
<?php
$id = (int) $_SESSION['id'];

$query = $conn->query ("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE customerid = '$id' ") or die (mysqli_error());
$fetch = $query->fetch_array ();
$customer_id=$fetch['customerid'];
if($id!=$customer_id){
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <td>No Order Yet!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}else if($id==$customer_id){
    while($row=$query->fetch_array ()){
        echo"
        \\code
        ";  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$query->fetch_array ()` __one__, `$query->fetch_array ()` __two__.

Comment: Because you already fetched it line 5. Also learn how to make prepared statements, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: do you work with pdo or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You call `fetch_array ()` twice, that's way you miss the first record. If I understand your logic correctly, try to output all the rows from your statement, then do additional check for empty result set.

```
<?php
    # Statement
    $id = (int) $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE customerid = '$id' ") or die (mysqli_error());

    # Rows output
    while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
        echo "";
    }

    # Empty result. Check record count after all the rows in the result have been retrieved.
    if ($query->num_rows = 0) {
        echo 
            "<table>
            <tr><td>No Order Yet!</td></tr>
            </table>";
    )       
?>
```